# How come whenever I connect a monitor via the mini display port, the WiFi signal drops to below 1Mbps?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, multiple-monitors

I have a client machine (System 76 Gazelle) that is running Pop_Os 19.10 with one monitor connected via HDMI. Every time I connect another monitor via mini displayport, the WiFi speed drops from ~150Mbps to under 1Mbps. Why on earth is this happening?

Edit: Some screenshots of pinging google before and after plugging in the third monitor

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lzF1.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky6dh.png)

Comment: Ping a site before and after connecting the monitor and post to the question to further clarify.

Comment: I have this problem on my RasPi-3.  In my case, it is caused by interference produced by the HDMI cable due to poor shielding on the motherboard.  Also in my case, a higher quality cable did not solve the problem.

Comment: @NiallUK - I added some screenshots of my ping responses

Comment: @taskermaster44 Please do not post text as image. You can simply select and copy text from the command-line and paste it into your question.

Comment: Try a ferrite snap-on over the HDMI cable. https://www.amazon.com/stardrift-10-Pack-Diameter-Ferrite-Suppressor/dp/B015RAZTIA

Comment: @Tim_Stewart suggestion is certainly worth a shot.  That didn't solve the problem for me.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas - these two things really shouldn't interfere with one another. That comment is just a shot in the dark based off of past weird issues I have had with micro-controllers and cheap rf transducers (also unshielded). The OP should update the question with the computer hardware it's running on honestly, if not no one will be able to give an authoritative answer.